# Crash when trying to call [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, segmentation-fault

I have an app that I've collected crash reports for that I can't reproduce. I have a view controller that is simply calling `[super didReceiveMemoryWarning]` when handling its own memory warning (yes, I know I don't need to do this, but that doesn't solve the problem I'm having right now either). Once the parent UIViewController tries to call purgeMemoryForReason it crashes with

Here is the relevant trace info:

```
Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x90000008
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x361dbf78 objc_msgSend + 16
1   UIKit                               0x31fbf499 -[UIViewController purgeMemoryForReason:] + 65
2   MyApp                               0x00016f0d -[AttributesViewController didReceiveMemoryWarning] (AttributesViewController.m:76)
3   Foundation                          0x30c5b4ff __57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke_0 + 19
4   CoreFoundation                      0x34d86547 ___CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke_0 + 71
5   CoreFoundation                      0x34d12097 _CFXNotificationPost + 1407
6   Foundation                          0x30bcf3eb -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 67
7   Foundation                          0x30bd0c1b -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:] + 31
8   UIKit                               0x31f8a271 -[UIApplication _performMemoryWarning] + 81
9   UIKit                               0x31f8a36b -[UIApplication _receivedMemoryNotification] + 175
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x30de42e1 _dispatch_source_invoke + 517
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x30de1b81 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 53
12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x30de1ec1 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF$VARIANT$mp + 157
13  CoreFoundation                      0x34d8d2ad __CFRunLoopRun + 1269
14  CoreFoundation                      0x34d104a5 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 301
15  CoreFoundation                      0x34d1036d CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105
16  GraphicsServices                    0x3600c439 GSEventRunModal + 137
17  UIKit                               0x31e06e7d UIApplicationMain + 1081
18  MyApp                               0x0000243b main (main.m:15)
```

I wish I could reproduce the error, but no matter how many times I trigger a memory warning on my test devices or the simulator I can't get this to happen. Any help as to what I can possibly look for would be appreciated, as I have tried looking and haven't found any information that has pointed me at the potential issue. Thanks!

**EDIT**: As I stated, I'm not doing anything in `didReceiveMemoryWarning`:

```
- (void) didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}
```

Yes, I know I don't need to do this. I plan on removing this code (I don't even know why I still have it in there), but I want to make sure I have the source of my problem fixed. I also haven't implmented `viewDidUnload` in `AttributesViewController`. I should have also mentioned I'm using ARC, but I'm not sure if that matters here or not.

From the feedback I've received the memory warning occurs when the camera is used (`UIImagePickerController` with source type `UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera`). `AttributesViewController` is presented modally by a view controller two levels above the one presenting `UIImagePickerController`, and they don't share any objects or other data. I know the camera frequently causes memory warnings, so I'm not sure if `UIImagePickerController` is related in any way other than the fact that its a memory hog.

I have Xcode set to always run the analyzer, and that hasn't come up with any issues. I've also ran the code through the Zombies and Leaks instruments and haven't been able to reproduce the problem or find any other issues.

Comment: Have you tried enabling zombies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you doing in your didReceiveMemoryWarning? Are you freeing any memory? Closing the view? What? Post code! [I see that you posted a little more code. Thanks.]

If not, the problem that caused the didReceiveMemoryWarning will not be resolved, and thus attempts future attempts to allocate more memory (i.e. alloc new objects) may start to fail. Thus, any code dependent upon those objects will fail. Is your code actually checking for the return values of all the times where you alloc something new?

More importantly, have you identified why you're receiving these memory warnings? Sure, gracefully handling low memory situations is critical, but preventing them, if humanly possible, is just as (if not more) important. Have you run your code through the Analyzer (<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>)? Have you profiled your app (<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>) to identify any sources of leaks?

**Update:**

Thanks for sharing your clarifications. Frankly, I'm running short on ideas, but a few more thoughts:

1. It's tough to diagnose (much less fix) when you are unable to reproduce the problem. That really seems like the priority. If you're testing on iPhone 4 or 4S, you're enjoying 512MB DRAM, but the 3G only has 256MB, and the 3 has 128MB. Are you testing on newer devices, whereas the users might have [less capable devices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iphone#Model_comparison)? Or are your crash logs from devices that are comparably equipped? Seems like you might get didReceiveMemoryWarning at different times depending upon the device configurations, and thus might make it harder to manifest the crash the users see.
2. Why is the app crashing? It could stem from `didReceiveMemoryWarning` being unable to free sufficient memory for continued operation (i.e. subsequent `alloc`s of needed objects are failing), but I'm not sure that this is indicated by your crash log. The log makes me wonder if you are doing any [Key Value Observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) or any [NSNotificationCenter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSNotificationCenter) logic? I ask because you could imagine problems stemming from an observed object having been released without removing the observer. I ask that because I see the `addObserver:selector:name:object:` reference and don't know if that's something Cocoa is did in the background, or whether your app is doing itself. (And it might be unrelated.) Are all the crash logs showing a similar call stack?
3. Does the app generally check to make sure it's various pointers are non-nil? Again, I'd expect a slightly different crash log, but it seems like it would be prudent to be extra cautious about checking for nil values to make sure that `purgeMemoryForReason` didn't release something behind the scenes on you.
4. And I guess the only other suggestion is whether all of your didReceiveMemoryWarning's and viewDidUnload's are releasing everything they can to minimize the impact of the the memory warning, ensuring that the app survives this low memory situation. It looks like the standard [didReceiveMemoryWarning](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW4) will try to unload views that are not active, so you probably want to make sure those are cleaning up the memory properly. Per the [Managing Your Memory Efficiently](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW10), you want to make sure that you're freeing your view's objects in your `viewDidUnload` or `didReceiveMemoryWarning`.

Sorry I don't have more constructive suggestions. Hopefully someone else will be able to come through with some better ideas.

Comment: I added additional detail in the post.

Comment: I also modified my answer accordingly, but I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will take these suggestions and scrub through my code and see if I can find anything I haven't seen yet.

Comment: I did find that there was a single retained view on that view controller that I wasn't setting to nil in `viewDidUnload`. Since I found this one I also found a few other places where I needed to do this. I made this fix a couple of weeks ago and haven't gotten another crash report for this issue, so I think that did it.

I thought I had already done all this, so I'm glad you mentioned it or I may not have looked again. Thanks for your help!